# Is it possible to poll a kqueue's file descriptor with `select()`?

Tags: macos, select, freebsd, kqueue

When you create a kqueue with `kqueue()` you get back a file descriptor. But it appears that this file descriptor cannot be meaningfully polled with `select()`. I understand that the *standard* way to poll/read from a `kqueue()` is with `kevent(...)` but I'm trying to integrate with some legacy code that polls file descriptors using `select()`.

The goal here was to be able to fire a "user event" that can be detected by this `select`-based polling mechanism (even if the event eventually needs to be "consumed" using `kevent()` later). This looked like the kind of thing `EVFILT_USER` was born to do, but a quick experiment indicates that `select()` doesn't report the kqueue's fd as being ready to read when an event is added (and triggered) in the kqueue, it just times out (or blocks forever). (But an equivalent `kevent()` call *does* see/return the event.)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just not possible to poll a kqueue's fd with `select()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The paper](https://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf), describing kqueue/kevent says (sect 6.5):

> Since an ordinary file descriptor references the kqueue, it can take
>   part in any operations that normally can per - formed on a descriptor.
>   The application may select(), poll(), close(), or even create a kevent
>   referencing a kqueue;

This is indeed the case for FreeBSD, i've checked this with following code:

```
  struct kevent e;
  fd_set fdset;
  int kq=kqueue();

  EV_SET(&e, 1, EVFILT_USER, EV_ADD, 0, 0, NULL);
  kevent(kq, &e, 1, 0, 0, 0); // register USER event filter

  EV_SET(&e, 1, EVFILT_USER, EV_ADD, NOTE_TRIGGER, 0, NULL);
  kevent(kq, &e, 1, 0, 0, 0); // trigger USER event

  FD_ZERO(&fdset);
  FD_SET(kq,&fdset);

  select(FD_SETSIZE,&fdset, 0, 0, 0); // wait for activity on kq

  int res = kevent(kq, 0, 0, &e, 1, 0); // get the event
```